# How can I configure Jenkins to take a parameter, change it and pass to an Ant script? (!)

Tags: maven, jenkins, ant

I realise this is probably a sub-optimal way to achieve what I'm trying to, but there are limitations I can't get round...

Given an existing Jenkins build runs a script after a maven war build, that script is an ant script to which parameters are passed.

Now I want to change the value of one of those Ant properties, using the value passed in to the build as a Jenkins parameter.

So when I call the Ant script, I want to be able to do something like:

```
my.ant.property = $build-parameter + "a constant string"
```

At the moment the errors in the log suggest $build-parameter isn't being parsed to its value, instead the value passed to the Ant script is the literal '$build-parameter'

EDIT:
I've since discovered the reason the value didn't end up in Ant script was because of a hyphen ( '-' ) in the Jenkins build parameter name.

So now the question is how do I concat that with a constant String prior to passing to Ant?

```
my.ant.property = $buildparameter + "a constant string"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using "Inject environment variables to the build process".

```
ANEWVAR=${builderparameter}aStringToAppend
```

Then, in the Invike Ant task:

```
ant.someprop=$ANEWVAR
```